# AWS : Redis with Drupal 8

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I already setup Redis cache with node type 'cache.t2.medium' on AWS

Below configuration I have in Drupal `settings.php`

```
$settings['redis.connection']['interface'] = 'PhpRedis';
$settings['redis.connection']['host']      = 'xxx.cache.amazonaws.com';  // Your Redis instance AWS hostname.
$settings['redis.connection']['port']      = '6379';

$settings['cache']['default'] = 'cache.backend.redis';
$settings['cache_prefix'] = 'production_';
$settings['container_yamls'][] = $app_root . '/modules/contrib/redis/example.services.yml';
$settings['container_yamls'][] = $app_root . '/modules/contrib/redis/redis.services.yml';
```

Although above setups is there, If website hits more than 200 users it is creating issue and website goes down. On removal above settings it works fine.

What I am missing in Redis setup?

Comment: What issues do you get? Any specific error messages you can share?

Comment: It gives Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RedisException' with message 'Redis server went away'

Comment: Are you monitoring the redis server? Anything unusual?